# What is the difference between \@@par and \par?

Tags: macros, paragraphs, package-writing, documentclass-writing

In LaTeX internal code I came accross `\@@par`. How is this different from `\par` or `\newline`. When should I use `\@@par` if I am writing a package or class file?

In general, there are so many other internal commands/macros (e.g., `\z@`, `\p@`, `\protected@edef`, etc) in LaTeX which I come accross while studying the internal code. Is there some documentation available regarding when and how to use them if I am writing a package or class file? Should I really bother about them at all?

Comment: `\@@par` and `\@par`  are only copies of `\par` (using `\let`) to save the meaning of the TeX primitive `\par`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. Thanks! I have updated my question while you were answering, I guess.

Comment: Yes, obviously -- I didn't notice the update. You could have a look into `source2e`, which describes the internals of the LaTeX Kernel. If you don't want to bother with such low-level kernel macros you can use some intermediate packages such as `etoolbox` etc. even in your class or package file to simplify some setups. `\z@` and `\p@` are just dimension registers, `\protected@edef` prevents expansion of the defined macro, making it robust and non-fragile

Comment: In addition, the vertical spacing introduced by `\par` is generally bigger than the value used by `\newline`

Comment: `\@@par` has the same meaning has `\endgraf` so this question is essentially the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96865/when-is-it-better-to-use-par-than-endgraf

Comment: Probably it would be best to focus your question on one area. There are lots of internal/programming macros in LaTeX2e, some of which are generally useful. That's quite distinct from asking about `\par` _versus_ `\@@par`, which is a good question but can't really be covered in the same answer as say `\protected@edef`.

Comment: Combined together, all the comments/answers given have answered my question. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In LaTeX the `\par` command gets redefined several times during a run over a document. For example, inside a `tabular` it does nothing: an input such as

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
\ttfamily\meaning\par
\end{tabular}
```

would print

```
macro:->.
```

(after the colon the parameter text is shown; after `->` up to the period the replacement text is shown). This way, users aren't bothered with empty lines inside a `tabular`.

In a `center`, `flushleft` or `flushright` environment, the definition is more complicated, but eventually the *macro* `\par` will execute `{\@@par}`, where `\@@par` is defined in the kernel by

```
\let\@@par\par
```

at a moment when `\par` still has its primitive meaning. In normal situations, `\par` will have the primitive meaning and, in general, one should use `\par` in macros.

Another example: when a `\parbox` or `minipage` is started, the `\@parboxrestore` command is executed, which also does `\let\par\@@par`. Why? Because the `\parbox` or `minipage` could be in a `tabular` or any other place where `\par` has been redefined.

The kernel has an interesting set of macros:

```
\def\@setpar#1{\def\par{#1}\def\@par{#1}}
\def\@par{\let\par\@@par\par}
\def\@restorepar{\def\par{\@par}}
```

The macro `\@setpar` changes the meaning of `\par` and `\@par`; why making a copy of the new meaning of `\par` into `\@par`? Because one can always say `\@restorepar` which will restore the meaning of `\par` as defined with `\@setpar`, in cases when it's not certain that `\par` has the wanted meaning. The default definition of `\@par` is to restore the primitive meaning.

Of course, grouping plays an essential role here. For instance, `\par` does nothing in `tabular`, but as soon as `\end{tabular}` is executed, `\par` will get back the meaning it had before `\begin{tabular}`. So a restoration with `\let\par\@@par` is rarely needed; an exception is `\@parboxrestore`, that's intended to bring LaTeX into a fresh state as if a new document should be started (we're in a `\parbox` or `minipage` and this indeed makes sense).

Your question has probably been prompted by the line

```
\newenviron{solution}{}{\xappto{\temp@solnlist}{\solutionbody {\@@par}}}
```

in your code at [Problems using listxadd and xappto](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245510/problems-using-listxadd-and-xappto)

Well, this is a place where a plain `\par` should be used:

```
\newenviron{solution}
  {}
  {\xappto{\temp@solnlist}{\expandonce{\solutionbody}\noexpand\par}}
```

The `\noexpand` is needed because of `\xappto` and the fact that we want `\par` to be stored, not its expansion at the uncontrolled moment the `\xappto` command is performed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find what a command does is to create a minimal and run:

```
\makeatletter\ttfamily
\meaning\par \\
\meaning\@@par \\
\meaning\p@
```

As you go along studying the LaTeX2e kernel you can grow this minimal with notes etc.

The best study source for coding LaTeX2e style packages and macros is the source itself, as well as packages. All these assignments were done to save memory at the time and are unessecary in a modern class, where I would opt for readabilty.

Don't start a modern class from scratch, rather start from an existing class. I suggest you have a look at the `tufte-book` for inspiration. The class started from another base class and also used packages effectively.